# Convert legacy MFC DAO application to use Access 2013

Tags: c++, mfc, ado, dao

I have a legacy application from VC6.0 and I am upgrading it to VS2013. I converted the .mdb format to .accdb for Access 2013, but DAO is too old for it.

I have been looking online for help for this issue, but can only find things for VB which does not apply for MFC/C++.

Does anyone know of any guide I could use for this ? Heard about ACEDAO but can't find anything to upgrade either.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Simply switch to **ODBC**. So you'll have to change `CDaoDatabase` -> `CDatabase`, `CDaoRecordset` -> `CRecordset`, etc. There should be no problems. The API is pretty much the same.